# How can I make menu items into two seperate buttons with different functions?

Tags: menus, css, javascript

The page with the problem: www.byes.hankens.net
Theme: Divi Theme, by ElegantThemes
Platform: Wordpress

I'm currently developing a webpage for the company I work in, and have a tiny problem with the mobile/tablet menu.

THE PROBLEM:
If I click the parent menu item, for example, menu item a; it will only toggle the submenu, and not function as a direct link.

WHAT I WANT:
I want the parent items to function as a link on the left side, and the (+) symbol on the right side as a toggle button.

I hope I made my self clear! Check the screenshots to gain a better understanding :)

[image: Problem]
[image: What I want]

Thanks guys!

Comment: If you have a question about the inner workings of a third party plugin/theme, you have a better chance of getting an answer at its author's forum

Answer (score 0):

You need to create your own `Nav Walker` to add HTML entity for parent menus. Which is clickable and toggle the sub menu.

@see:

**Plugin for reference**
https://wordpress.org/plugins/responsive-menu/

**Tutorial**
https://wptheming.com/2013/03/drop-down-menu-indicator/
http://shinraholdings.com/62/custom-nav-menu-walker-function/